# Make Blockchiain inquiries using Rbitcoin

Tags: r, bitcoin, blockchain

I need to get some information associated to all the transactions made in the Blockchain since last January. Specifically, I need the transaction fee and the block height of every transaction.

I assume that I need to use this command: `blockchain.api.query(..., method, verbose = getOption("Rbitcoin.verbose", 0))`but don´t know how.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to add `r` tag in questions related to Rbitcoin.
Regarding help with `blockchain.api.query` you should find the answer in the package documentation.
You may also see `blockchain.api.process` as it is related function.
Regarding what you want to achieve, Rbitcoin - particularly the backend of `blockchain.api.*` functions is the blockchain.info api, and it is not the right solution for you.
I recommend you to use json-RPC to locally stored blockchain, not the remote one on blockchain.info.
There is an open ticket in Rbitcoin repo to support quering data from locally stored blockchain: [Rbitcoin#8](https://github.com/jangorecki/Rbitcoin/issues/8).

---

**Update 2015-11-08:**

I've released bitcoin daemon R client as separate package, see: [jangorecki/rbitcoind](https://github.com/jangorecki/rbitcoind).